# How to add input controls on click of google map marker popup

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this code is to show the info text on the pop of click of google marker.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "Add your popup content here"
              });
```

I need to show input controls like text box, dropdown(netsted dropwdown) on this pop up instead of plain info text.

Can somebody provide sample code for this , either in angular js etc.

Help is highly appreceated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called custom html marker.

Basically what you do is create a marker and then programmatically inject html control in there like this:

```
function CustomMarker(latlng, map, args) {
    this.latlng = latlng;   
    this.args = args;   
    this.setMap(map);   
}
```

Then set the prototype of the marker:

```
CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
```

Then implement the draw function where you can create any html control like div, textbox, drop down etc.:

```
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {

    var self = this;

    var div = this.div;

    if (!div) {

        div = this.div = document.createElement('div');

        div.className = 'marker';

        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        div.style.width = '20px';
        div.style.height = '20px';
        div.style.background = 'blue';

        if (typeof(self.args.marker_id) !== 'undefined') {
            div.dataset.marker_id = self.args.marker_id;
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event) {            
            google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
        });

        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    }

    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);

    if (point) {
        div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = point.y + 'px';
    }
};
```

You have to still implement the other functions like `remove, getPosition` etc. as necessary. Details can be found here: https://humaan.com/blog/custom-html-markers-google-maps/

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thanks :)